# jboss 7.1 jndi binding programmatically

Tags: jboss, jndi

How to bind to jndi custom object programmatically on jboss 7.1?
Context.bind throws exception indicating that jndi context is read-only.
Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible at all. The following code works in JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final:

```
@Stateless
public class JndiEjb {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JndiEjb.class);

    public void registerInJndi() {
        try {
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            context.bind("java:global/JndiEjb", this);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Failed to register bean in jndi: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public void retrieveFromJndi() {
        try {
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            Object lookup = context.lookup("java:global/JndiEjb");
            if(lookup != null && lookup instanceof  JndiEjb) {
                LOGGER.debug("Retrieval successful.");
                JndiEjb jndiEjb = (JndiEjb)lookup;
                jndiEjb.helloWorld();
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Failed to register bean in jndi: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public void helloWorld() {
        LOGGER.info("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

If you call first `registerInJndi()` and afterwards `retrieveFromJndi()` the object will be looked up and the method `helloWorld()`is called.

You will find more information [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI+Reference).

Comment: And registerInJndi() should be called in servlet with load-on-startup = 0(And maybe from startup ejb service). Here we can edit jndi without exception.